# how to declare an eccuation using array without repeating it? (I am a begginer :D)

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, printf

I am a begginer and I tried to make a programm which prints out two polinomions (one of grade 2 and one of grade 3) I want to do this with arrays so I can work with it easily for other steps, but my polinomions are repeating 4 times while running my programm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stlib.h>
int main(){
    int a[4];
    int b[3];
    int i, j;

    printf("type 4 numbers:");

    for(i=0; i<4; ++i){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<4; ++i){
        printf("%dx^3+%dx^2+%dx+%d\n", a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
    }
    
    
    printf("Type 3 numbers:");

    for(j=0; j<3; ++j){
        scanf("%d", &b[j]);
    }
    for(j=0; j<3; ++j){
        printf("%dx^2+%dx+%d\n", b[0],b[1],b[2]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I print out my eccuation, the eccuation reppeats 4 times, which I guess happens because of the loop...
How can I improve my code so this doesn't happen.
Sorry for my english :D and thanks for your time!

Comment: If you don't want it to print repeatedly, don't put the print in a loop...

Comment: @interjay thanks, but can you give me a suggestion on how to make, or declare a polynomial in a better way? it would help a lot :D

Comment: If you are a beginner, I recommend your first learn basic concepts such as how conditions and loops work. Then work out how the C syntax works. Then what you can do with the program as well as the standard library.  Then start with something simpler than polys. Arrays are "cool" and you can do a lot with them, but they have a different purpose. And while you can retrofit them to include equations, you'll find it's harder then to simply use calculus as it's meant in the language. Don't try to reinvent the wheel as you will accidentally drop it on your foot :)

Comment: @TheNomad thank you very much for your advice, I will give my best to follow it. :D

Answer (score 0):

It is because within the for loops you are repeatedly outputting the same string as for example

```
for(i=0; i<4; ++i){
    printf("%dx^3+%dx^2+%dx+%d\n", a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
}
```

You need to remove the for statements. Or it will be much better to write a separate function as for example

```
void display_polynome( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( i != 0 ) putchar( '+' );
        
        if ( i == n - 1 ) 
        {
            printf( "%dx\n", a[i] );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "%dx^%zu", a[i], n - i - 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
display_polynome( a, 4 );
display_polynome( b, 3 );
```